# Vba excel replacing string based on table values

Tags: excel, str-replace, vba

I have code which replaces part of string in column A in sheet "Data" with new value written in Column B of sheet "Filter".

Column A of sheet "Filter" has old values, and Column B has values after replacement, see picture:

[image]

I know how to replace for example "Griffith RV8" into "Griffith RV-8" but how can I do that replacement plus remove all characters in front of that replaced string?

Griffith RV8 = RV-8

```
Sub Substitutions()

Dim rngData     As Range
Dim rngLookup   As Range
Dim Lookup      As Range

With Sheets("Data")
    Set rngData = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

With Sheets("Filter")
    Set rngLookup = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

For Each Lookup In rngLookup
    If Lookup.Value <> "" Then
        rngData.Replace What:=Lookup.Value, _
                        Replacement:=Lookup.Offset(0, 1).Value, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        MatchCase:=False
    End If
Next Lookup

End Sub
```

Comment: Why aren't you replacing "Griffith RV8" with "RV-8" ?  This doesn't seem like a simple replace - there is some other rule you need to apply?

Comment: Because RV8 will show up with dozens of different words in front of it and all I need from that string is RV-8 and whatever is after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wildcards to replace parts of a string.

```
Sub Example()

    Range("A1") = "Where in the World is Carmen Sandiego?"

    Range("A1").Replace "*Carmen", "Who is Micheal"

    Range("A3") = "Hello World! How are You?"

    Range("A3").Replace "!*", "? Can you hear me!?"

    Range("A5") = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

    Range("A5").Replace "??H??", "fgHij"

    ' You can escape the wildcards using "\"
    Range("A7") = "? not escaped"

    Range("A8") = "WHO? WHO!"

    Range("A8").Replace "WHO?", "WHO ARE YOU?"

    Range("A10") = "? was escaped using a backslash \?"

    Range("A11") = "WHO? WHO!"

    Range("A11").Replace "WHO\?", "WHO ARE YOU?"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rngData.Replace What:= "* " & Lookup.Value, _
                Replacement:=Lookup.Offset(0, 1).Value, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    MatchCase:=False
```

will replace `[some text here][space]Lookup.Value` with `Lookup.Offset(0, 1).Value`